# Determine if a button is currently being left clicked (click held down)?

Tags: javascript

In plain JavaScript, I want to determine if a button is currently being pressed down.

I do not want to use a solution that sets flags on the mousedown, mouseup or any other mouse events please

There is a loop, triggered by a mouse down, this loop is running after a setTimeout. The mouseup, mousedown listeners are not available - I want to do something like:

```
let mainButton = document.getElementById("main-button");
// inside the callback of a setTimeout somewhere in the distant future.....
if(mainButton.??? isDown/style.isCurrrentlyClicked){
     //doSomething
}
```

Again, no mouseup/down flags are going to be use for this. Thanks.

Comment: "no mouseup/down flags are going to be use for this" that's too bad, because there isn't another solution.

Comment: If you'd done any research on the [HTMLButtonElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement) API you'd know that there isn't. It's not a matter of "we'll see". If you want to hold out hope that eventually there's an alternative introduced into the DOM API, be my guest.

Comment: Maybe there is a solution using the css - checking the applied class etc. I have been looking into it, but did not find an elegant solution yet

Comment: Can you give more background? It sounds like your code is running in a somewhat untrusted way on a 3rd party website? Is that a bad inference? Any reason why you can't describe the problem more? The one idea you could explore is to investigate the color of the button if you know that it has onHover, onClick, etc. properties set. (nvm, just saw your comment)

Comment: @Ben Fletcher The button is being held down to generate more elements on the page. It can be released - and clicked again, or double clicked - many things, but at a certain point, we need to check if it is being held down. Simply put, we are not going to use mouse down/up listeners - there are too many corner cases in this instance. The onHover onClick might be somehting.......

Comment: Usually when something quirky like this comes up that tries to bend the language or browser to its will, I have to ask if the design is wrong ... that said, I wonder if you could trigger a CSS3 transition on click/hover (and maybe the transition has a start delay) and then listen to the transition start event?

Comment: The question needs to be revised.  The first sentence starts off with **"In plain JavaScript"**.  By involving CSS, that requirement isn't met.

Comment: Don't.  People have put in some effort to help you.  The person who wrote an answer deserves some rep if that answer helped you.

Comment: "there are too many corner cases in this instance" what corner cases are you referring to? [Tracking via flags is straightforward](https://codepen.io/zzzzBov/pen/vJvLdr).

Comment: @Brian feel free to answer your own question if you have something that works.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( $( '#btn:active' ).length ) // your button is active
```

Comment: Cool. I'll test this tomorrow without the jQuery . Thanks @flcoder

Comment: Can probably use document.querySelector which will work for 97.7% of all users according to https://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector

Comment: More direct than my solution

Answer (score 1):

You can play with the style, but this is very hacky

```js
setInterval(() => {
  let button = $('#btn');
  let color = button.css('background-color');
  if (color == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)') {
    $('#status').text('Not clicked');
  } else {
  debugger;  $('#status').text('Clicked');
  }
}, 300);
```

```css
button {
  background-color: #FFF
}

button:active {
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
<p id='status'></p>
```

Take into account that using a setInterval instead of a event handler is just a polling approach: if the interval is too short the perfomance will suffer, but if it is too long the responsivity will be crappy

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this! Yeah, this could be a way of doing it all right. Would remove the need for eventHandler flag setting. I'll see if there is a more generic solution along these lines

Comment: Be careful as it stays in hover state if you mouse out and away whilst still pressing the mousedown button - don't know if that might cause you an issue or not.

Comment: @DarrenCrabb Definitely this approach is not desired one by any developer

Comment: Also, it's not cross-browser - just tested in IE and it fails.

Comment: I think it may be better to use a property that is perhaps more consistently defined between browsers - maybe padding / margin or something. Yes, it's a novel approach and does negate the need for flags.